# Spring Cloud Stream: ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.codec.kryo.KryoRegistrar

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to workout a Spring Cloud Stream app using Kafka as broker. pom file looks like :-

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.4.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.cloud.version>Camden.SR3</spring.cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Main class:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BootWebappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BootWebappApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Trying to run this gives back this :-

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.codec.kryo.KryoRegistrar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
```

I think dependencies version are messed up somewhere - I am using latest versions on this date.

What are right versions to be used for 'spring.boot.version' & 'spring.cloud.version' if that is actually the problem

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR5</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: that gave back -  'Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:jar is missing.'

Comment: it is using the local repo to check for the dependencies, may be it is not downloading the new jars. can you cross check in ur .m2 Repo.

Comment: Brixton.SR5 is itself the parent pom, it rather has child poms, spring-cloud-stream is one of the child, which itself is parent pom to number of child cloud-stream jars. (Just for info), may be that will give you any idea in finding the perfect jars.